# Write excel Function FILTER with Python

Tags: python, excel, function, filter, openpyxl

I try use function in my excel sheet because after I run the code all function is breaking ( start with {=FILTER instead =Filter(    )

That why I write directly in cell the function.

```
from tkinter import filedialog, scrolledtext, messagebox, ttk
from tkinter import *
import pandas
from decimal import Decimal
import openpyxl
import os
import re



book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename,keep_vba=True,data_only=TRUE)
```

`book['POF Workbook']['Q33']= '=COUNTIF(B2:B10, ">0")'`   => ok working

`book['POF Workbook']['D33']= 'FILTER(Table1,Table1[POF "'"#]='POF Workbook'!A3,"+'"No data"'+")"` => no working

in excel I have :

```
FILTER(Table1,Table1[POF "#]='POF Workbook'!A3,"No data")
```

when I try to write : `book['POF Workbook']['D33']= '=FILTER(Table1,Table1[POF "'"#]='POF Workbook'!A3,"+'"No data"'+")"` nothing happened

I can't find a solution during 3 days :(

[image]

Comment: Excel is almost certainly aliasing the table names. Your best bet is to look at the source code of a worksheet for a relevant example and to base your code on this.

Comment: How I can do it ? have you a exemple please ?